# Python send email rotate proxies in smtplib

Tags: python-3.x, smtplib

I'm trying to send emails with smtplib, which works. I also added proxy support, which works. But now I'm trying to rotate proxies, but I always get an error "an integer is required not type str".
I guess it cannot be done, I mean to call var inside smtplib connection func, but I hope that you can help me out.

This is my code:

```
ips = []
csvFile = csv.reader(open('proxies.csv', 'r', encoding='UTF-8', errors='strict', buffering=1))
for row in csvFile:
  ips.append(row[0])

for ip in ips:
    socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS4, ip, port)
                    socks.wrapmodule(smtplib)
                    smtp = smtplib.SMTP()
           #etc...
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is `type(port)`?

Comment: It's standard format, e.g. 103.501.50225 for proxy and in another csv I have ports, which read ok, if that's what you meant?

Comment: The port argument most likely has to be an `int`. If you're reading that from a CSV then chances are your port is a string.

Comment: I did try with int(proxy) and int(port) in the connection of smtplib, but it throws error "invalid literal for string() with base 10 '103.501.50225'".

Comment: I did not say `proxy` has to be an integer. I said `port` most likely needs to be an integer.